# Не выводит сообщение об ошибке на страницу

Tags: php

Всем привет. Проблема такая: не выводит сообщение об ошибке которое в переменной. То есть если на прямую присвоить переменной слово ошибка то выведет. А вот через $_REQUEST из строки URL не извлекается.

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['error_message'])){
$error_massage = preg_replace("/\\\\/", '', $_REQUEST['error_message']);
}else{
    $error_massage = "вы здесь оказались из - за сбоя работы программы";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ошибка</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header"><h1>PHP & MySQL</h1></div>
    <div id="example"><h2>Пример</h2></div>

    <div id="content">
        <h1>Нам очень жаль...</h1>

        <?php echo "{$error_message}" ?>
<p>Ошибка</p>  
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: наверно потому что message != massage?

Comment: почему не равно то?

Comment: оно не как не ищет. $error_message = "Ошибка", тогда вывод будет работать. $error_message = $_REQUEST['error_message'] - не выводит.

Comment: от куда error_message в принципе берётся?

Comment: ну в URL же можно прописать запрос типа: site01/scripts/show_error.php?error_message=error   и тогда должно быть выведено "error" после "Нам очень жаль..."

Comment: если просто сделать так: $error_message = "Ошибка"; то выводиться слово "Ошибка".